# Change style depending on RouterURL in Angular 8

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-components

I have one component named 'NavigatorComponent'. There I have my '**routerLink**'. All the urls are attached to different components. Now the scenario is I have to change the link color depending on url it is currently. I am new to Angular and so I have no idea how to do it. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Below is the code snippet for Navigator.html and app-routing.module.ts file.

```
<ul>
   <li><a class="active" [routerLink] = "'/welcome-information'">Welcome Information</a></li>
   <li><a class="disable" [routerLink] = "'/your-plan'">Select Your Plan</a></li>
   <li><a class="disable" [routerLink] = "'/your-data'">Confirm Your Data</a></li>
   <li><a class="disable" [routerLink] = "'/bank-draft'">Bank Draft</a></li>
   <li><a class="disable" [routerLink] = "'/your-choice'">Finalize Your Choice</a></li>
</ul>

const routes: Routes = [
  {path: 'welcome-information' , component: WelcomeInformationComponent},
  {path: 'your-plan' , component: YourPlanComponent},
  {path: 'your-data' , component: YourDataComponent},
  {path: 'bank-draft' , component: BankDraftComponent},
  {path: 'your-choice' , component: YourChoiceComponent},
];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [routerLinkActive](https://angular.io/api/router/RouterLinkActive) directive.

This directive adds a CSS class to an element when the link's route becomes active.

```
<li><a  routerLinkActive="active" [routerLink] = "'/welcome-information'">Welcome Information</a></li>
<li><a  routerLinkActive="active"  class="disable" [routerLink] = "'/your-plan'">Select Your Plan</a></li>
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-router-basic-example-yuu4kj?embed=1&file=app/app.component.ts)

Comment: Thanks. Adrita. This is a real help. However, I would like to know is there any directive for visited link also? And how do I disable the other link with disable class?

Comment: @PiyaliGhosh I am not aware of visited link directive, you have to check. For disabled link, you can use `class="disable"`. I have added a demo. Check app.component.css as well

Answer (score 0):

You can use [RouterLinkActive](https://angular.io/api/router/RouterLinkActive) to add CSS class to your active link, Exp :

```
<li><a [routerLinkActive]="['class1', 'class2'] [routerLink] = "'/your-plan'">Select Your Plan</a></li>
```

Or

```
<li><a routerLinkActive="class1 class2" [routerLink] = "'/your-plan'">Select Your Plan</a></li>
```